# Writing py2.x and py3.x compatible code without six.text_type

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode, io, six

Given the `six.text_type` function. it's easy to write i/o code for unicode text, e.g. https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/malt.py#L188

```
fout.write(text_type(line))
```

But without the `six` module, it would require a `try-except` gymnastics that looks like this:

```
try:
    fout.write(text_type(line))
except:
    try:
        fout.write(unicode(line))
    except:
        fout.write(bytes(line))
```

What is the pythonic way to resolve the file writing a unicode line and ensuring the python script is py2.x and py3.x compatible?

Is the `try-except` above the pythonic way to handle the py2to3 compatibility? What other alternatives are there?

---

For more details/context of this question: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1080#issuecomment-134542174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what `six` does, and define `text_type` yourself:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    text_type = unicode
except NameError:
    # Python 3
    text_type = str
```

In any case, *never* use blanked `except` lines here, you'll be masking other issues entirely unrelated to using a different Python version.

It is not clear to me what kind of file object you are writing to however. If you are using `io.open()` to open the file you'll get a file object that'll always expect Unicode text, in both Python 2 and 3, and you should not need to convert text to `bytes`, ever.

Comment: Ingenious fix!!! Noted on the `bytes` conversion, I'll check how/why the bytes was used.